# NPM "google-spreadsheet" formatting a value added by .addRows()

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm using the NPM "google-spreadsheet" on a node.js project.

When I add some rows with the .addRows() command, sometimes the format is converted by Google sheet (like phone number).
I would like to add the values with the format I wanted ;)

This is an extract of my code.

I would like to write in the script that the content of the column 'phone_number' should be pure text.

```
const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require('google-spreadsheet');
const GS_creds= require('../xxxxxx.json');
const GS_concertannuel = new GoogleSpreadsheet('yyyyyyyyy');
await GS_concertannuel.useServiceAccountAuth(GS_creds);
await GS_concertannuel.loadInfo();
const GS_CA_tab_hebergements = GS_concertannuel.sheetsByTitle['hebergements'];
const ajout_gs_hebergements = GS_CA_tab_hebergements.addRows([{
                'identifiant': myIdentifiant,
                'phone_number': myPhoneNumber // 0909090909
            }]);
```

> THIS IS THE INPUT AND OUTPUT :
>
> INPUT : The phone number I have in the Database is **0909090909**.
>
> OUTPUT : The phone number copied in the Google Sheet with
> google-spreadsheet is **909090909** (without the first 0).
> The OUTPUT I would like is 0909090909, that means in string format and not
> number.

I read the documentation, but I don't understand. (https://theoephraim.github.io/node-google-spreadsheet/#/).

Despite the advertised "The most popular Google Sheets API wrapper for javascript / typescript" text, I don't find a lot of information on Internet.

I could try IA ;) Well I start by pair's help ;)

Thank you guys

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike for your reply :)
I put the input and output, hope it will help.
It is not your English, I have difficulties to speak well ;)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, as a simple modification, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
const ajout_gs_hebergements = GS_CA_tab_hebergements.addRows([{
                'identifiant': myIdentifiant,
                'phone_number': myPhoneNumber // 0909090909
            }]);
```

#### To:

```
const ajout_gs_hebergements = GS_CA_tab_hebergements.addRows(
   [
     {
       identifiant: myIdentifiant,
       phone_number: myPhoneNumber, // 0909090909
     },
   ],
   { raw: true }
 );
```

or

```
const ajout_gs_hebergements = GS_CA_tab_hebergements.addRows(
   [
     {
       identifiant: myIdentifiant,
       phone_number: "'" + myPhoneNumber, // 0909090909
     },
   ]
 );
```

- I thought that the reason for your current issue is due to By this modification, the value is put as a text.

#### Reference:

- [addRow(rowValues, options)](https://theoephraim.github.io/node-google-spreadsheet/#/classes/google-spreadsheet-worksheet?id=fn-addrow)

Comment: Thank you very much @Tanaike. It works perfectly well by adding "'" + myPhoneNumber. Thank you so much. I didn't think about this workaround, it will be useful in more situation ;)

Comment: @Julie Chaumard Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.